# Integrating Cytoscape in R Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am trying to integrate the code for generating a graph of LesMiserables network as a starting point to see if Cytoscape can be integrated with R shiny

Please find the code here :
https://www.r-bloggers.com/network-visualization-part-5-cytoscape-an-update-rcy3/

Though i am able to run and execute the code end to end in R ( With the correct RCy3 version and connection with Cytoscape )

Can someone help me with how can this integration be achieved with Shiny and Cytoscape .

I found one reference

## https://github.com/rmflight/shinyCytoscape but of less help to me

Comment: Hi Neha, you didn't state your problem.

Comment: Dear Mike , my issue is i am unable to link shiny and The cytoscape code in R pasted above and i have no idea on how can this happen , i did look at some of the previous work online but i dont get the idea of integrating both and working with each other